# Let $R=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\0&b\end{pmatrix}:a,b\in\Bbb Q\right\}$ be a ring and $I=\{A\in R:A^2=0\}$ ideal of $R.$ Show that $R/I\cong\Bbb Q.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

> Show that $R=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a\\0 & b\end{pmatrix}:a,b\in\Bbb Q\right\}$ is a subring of $M_2(\Bbb Q)$ and $I=\{A\in R:A^2=0\}$ is an ideal of $R.$ Finally, show that $R/I\cong \Bbb Q.$

I was able to show that $R=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a\\0 & b\end{pmatrix}:a,b\in\Bbb Q\right\}$, is a subring of $M_2(\Bbb Q)$ and $I=\{A\in R:A^2=0\}$ is an ideal of $R.$

However, I was not able to prove that
$R/I\cong \Bbb Q.$

My strategy was to find an epimorphism from $R$ to $\Bbb Q$ with kernel $I.$ If I was able to find one such mapping, then from First Isomorphism Theorem I could've said, $R/I\cong \Bbb Q.$

I tried constructing several epimorphisms $\phi$ from $R$ to $\Bbb Q$ such as, $\phi(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a\\0 & b\end{pmatrix})=a+b$ or $\phi(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a\\0 & b\end{pmatrix})=ab$ or $\phi(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a\\0 & b\end{pmatrix})=a+b-ab$ or $\phi(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a\\0 & b\end{pmatrix})=a+b-1$ or $\phi(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a\\0 & b\end{pmatrix})=(a-1)(b-1),$ for all $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a\\0 & b\end{pmatrix}\in R.$

However, none of them turned to be a valid homomorphism in the first case.

Finally, I tried to find *isomorphisms* from $R/I$ to $\Bbb Q.$

But this made me take a closer observation at what the set $R/I$ is?

This made me realise that $R/I=R$. So, the question now asks us to show that  $R\cong \Bbb Q.$ Now, this looks much confusing.

Any help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $R$ is not a subring of the ring of matrices because the identity is not in $R$.

Comment: Did you calculate what $I$ is? It's quite important to do so before trying to guess what the homomorphism is.

Comment: @Don subring need not have a (multiplicative) identity, e.g. $2\mathbb{Z}$ does not have an identity in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Ennar Yes, though I calculated what $I$ is, but still I wasn't able to guess.

Comment: Well, it's pointless to ask you what is it now that there's an answer, so I'll trust you on that. If I told you that there is a linear map $f\colon\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(a,b) = 0 \iff b = 0$, what would that linear map be? That map sends the line $\{(a,0)\}$ to $0$, but nothing else.

Comment: Anyway, your $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q^2$ as a vector space in an obvious way and $I$ is its $1$-dimensional subspace. So, if you can answer my previous question (replacing $\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb Q$ which doesn't matter), among all linear $f$ with such kernel, there's precisely one that will be multiplicative.

Comment: @AnuragA Well, I would say that the addition and multiplication of $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ are closed for $R$ and that $R$ is a ring with these operations, but I wouldn't say $R$ is a subring of $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$. The same for $2\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$; for me that's an ideal but not a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$. In any case, for this exercise this is just grammar; now it's clear what they're asking.

Answer (score 5):

Note that if $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&b\end{bmatrix} \in R$, then $A^2=0$ implies $\begin{bmatrix}0&ab\\0&b^2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, then $A$ must be of the form $\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Thus $I=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\, | \, a \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$.

Try the map $\phi:R \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ defined by
$$\phi\left(\begin{bmatrix}0
&a\\0&b\end{bmatrix}\right)=b.$$

Kernel of this map is $\ker(\phi)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\, | \, a \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}.$